# RootPane.get("something") with GWT Designer

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-designer

I've been working a little with GWT and I managed to do some small aplications.

But now I started playing with GWT Designer, there is a little thing that I just couldn´t acomplish yet.

When working with standard gwt, if I want to add some control or element, I just write this:

```
RootPane.get("something").add(somePanel);
```

And gwt renders that panel inside a div with id = something.

Now, I'm doing the same with GWT Designer but it renders at the left top  of the screen, I know that if i just move all the elements in the designer they will be displayed lower, but I want them rendered properly inside the div, wherever the div is located.

PS: Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when working with the designer the code generated was:

```
RootPane.get("something").add(somePanel, x, y);
```

So somehow that move the div to X,Y cordinates, justo to remove those cordinates and the panel will render properly inside the defined div.